# Python if string contains "foo" do this

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a twitter bot that responds to tweets containing certain strings from array `t`. I'm trying to write a conditional statement that restricts it from responding to tweets containing strings from another array, `a`. In theory it should work but it doesn't. The bot disregards the if/else statement. My code is as follows:

```
#I search for tweets to my bot's handle
twt = api.search(q='@samplehandle')

#list of specific strings we want to omit from responses
a = ['java',
     'swift']


#list of specific strings I want to check for in tweets and reply to
t = ['I love code',
     'python rocks',
     'javascript']

for c in twt:
    for b in a:
            if b not in c.text:
                for s in twt:
                    for i in t:
                        if i in s.text:
                            sn = s.user.screen_name
                            m = "@%s This is a lovely tweet" % (sn)
                            s = api.update_status(m, s.id)

            else:
                print "Null"
```

Thank you

Comment: You are iterating over `twt` multiple times (nested). Use more descriptive variable names instead of `c`, `b`, `a`, `s`, and `i`, and you'll have an easier time determining what is happening and where.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 with the double iteration of `twt` I assumed I could loop through all `twt` items (indexing with `c` first) then running a check if my conditions were met and subsequently responding to each approved tweet (indexing with `i`). Is this incorrect?

Comment: You are checking each tweet for each tweet (N^2). Only check each tweet once. Try using operators like `and` or `or` to form an expression for the full condition you'd like to check to approve a tweet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having a ton of nested for loops your program will be much more manageable if you make use of a function to determine if a tweet contains words in a specific list. I also changed your variable names because there's no way to work with a, b, c, d,

```
#list of specific strings we want to omit from responses
badWords = ['java', 'swift']

#list of specific strings I want to check for in tweets and reply to
goodWords = ['I love code', 'python rocks', 'javascript']


def does_contain_words(tweet, wordsToCheck):
    for word in wordsToCheck:
        if word in tweet:
            return True
    return False

for currentTweet in twt:
    #if the tweet contains a good word and doesn't contain a bad word
    if does_contain_words(currentTweet.text, goodWords) and not does_contain_words(currentTweet.text, badWords):
        #reply to tweet
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Racialz, I tried your solution but the console returned the error: `if doesContainWords(currentTweet.text, doRespondTo.text) and not doesContainWords(currentTweet.text, dontRespondTo):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: What is twt in your example? I thought it was a list of tweets, each you could get the text by doing .text?

Comment: I'm getting it to work using the exact code I posted. Make sure to include `twt=api.search(q="something")`. Can you post your full updated code now? Show everything except your twitter api key and tokens.

Comment: Oh great, I hadn't seen your edit. This is perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: By the way, one small thing you might want to change is to ignore cases. You might want to do `if word.upper() in tweet.upper()` to ignore cases. Right now the program will respond to 'python rocks' but not 'Python rocks'

Comment: Thank you. Will do